# Selenium in java unable to identify classname

Tags: java, selenium

Selenium webdriver is not able to identify this element by 'classname' as it has spaces .I cannot use 'name' as it has multiple element with same name.

```
<span id="Fn14906146202366285507890WSRP:TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMATSelectBoxIt" tabindex="0" class="selectboxit dropdownexpandalbe selectboxit-btn" name="TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMAT" unselectable="on" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="Fn14906146202366285507890WSRP:TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMATSelectBoxItOptions" aria-activedescendant="3" aria-label="Display Format" aria-live="assertive"><span id="Fn14906146202366285507890WSRP:TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMATSelectBoxItText" class="selectboxit-text" unselectable="on" data-val="2" style="max-width: 120px;">On Screen</span><span id="Fn14906146202366285507890WSRP:TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMATSelectBoxItArrowContainer" class="selectboxit-arrow-container" unselectable="on"><i id="Fn14906146202366285507890WSRP:TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMATSelectBoxItArrow" class="selectboxit-arrow selectboxit-default-arrow" unselectable="on"></i></span></span>
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the spaces, you can check multiple classes in a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".selectboxit.dropdownexpandalbe.selectboxit-btn"))
```

Or, you can also just check a single class:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".selectboxit"))
driver.findElement(By.className("selectboxit"))
```